# Continuous merges from Branch to Trunk

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn, branch, trunk

If I'm to use Tortoise-SVN in a situation where I'll be wanting to periodically merge from Trunk to Branch *and also* Branch to trunk, how should I be doing the latter?

The "Branch to Trunk" tutorials I've come across use the "Reintegrate a branch" command, but they only ever do it once. When I try and do it a second time, I get unexpected conflicts.

If I however use the "Merge a range of revisions" command, I can merge from branch back to trunk multiple times.

The [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html) say that a reintegrated branch is now useless, which I guess would explain the unexpected conflicts Im getting. But if using "Merge a range of revisions" allows more than one merge from branch to trunk, why use "Reintegrate a branch" that won't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. With SVN 1.7.x you can (according to docs) `--reintegrate` more than once. For 1.6 and early reintegration can be performed only once
2. With SVN, which *has support for mergeinfo* (1.6+) "sync merges" may not use rev-range - previous merges are written in mergeinfo in the same revisions **will not be** merged again (except cases of merging subtrees in the middle, where merge become crazy of detecting ranges)
3. Reintegration merge performed with special pre-condition, which decrease difference between nodes to *introduced only by merge-source* (for giant diffs and complex changes it can be huge plus)